AWS Personalise Recommendations Limit
We are working on an application that uses AWS Personalize for generating personalized product recommendations to users in our sales. I've noticed that the recommendations returned by both the AWS SDK is limited to 500 and the OpenSearch Personalize plugin ranking is limited to ranking the first 500 products in the search only. Our sales which we load for users can have upwards of 3000 products.
Context: When using the AWS SDK's getRecommendations or getPersonalizedRanking methods, the response contains a maximum of 500 recommendations, regardless of the dataset size or filtering applied. Similarly, when querying recommendations through the OpenSearch plugin, the same limit of 500 items applies to how much it re-ranks. I know there is the 'batch' job in the aws personalise but it also seems it is capped at 1000 recommendations per user and also a file size limit etc.
I need to retrieve more than 500 recommendations for certain scenarios, such as:
Displaying personalized catalogs for users or a sales they access.
Questions: What are the best practices to overcome this limit?
Some options I’ve considered:
Implementing multiple calls with varying inputs/filters - not sure if this can 'accurately' get all products as we wish to use real-time updates etc so some products may show multiple times? Also do not think pagination is supported officially by the api
Post-processing and merging results from multiple recommendation queries. Are there any efficient ways to paginate beyond the 500-item limit, especially when using the OpenSearch plugin? We would love for it to take into account all products and re-rank them correctly.

Is the 501th recommended element really of any value?

Well yes in a way let me put it this way
the open search plugin only re-ranks the first 500 based on its input - so how do you know what order to send it to aws personalise to ensure that the item 1200th in the list passed wouldn't be number 1?
Also then for the sdk/api - yes in a large e-commerce we have seen most people scroll all the way down to the 3000th product still adding items. It would be great if we could paginate correctly for the user continuously giving the top recommended products in order without having to keep track of what was already recommended 1500 items previously

Also even for the SDK/API it seems the 'filter' option is limitied in size to how many 'IDs' you wish to exclude etc

I think the gist should be that if your raw data is any good there should be no possibility for the 12000th item to be better ranked than the 1st. If I search for banana and OpenSearch returns me a few bananas, bandanas, other fruits, some vegetables, a lego banana and then at place 12000th it also includes a spaceship then even it am most spaceship interested person I should still not get that ranked as number one no matter how good it matches my personal interests because I simply did not search for it but a banana. No reasonable person looks at that many search results anyway.

Obviously possible that your 3000 items are so similar that all of them are relevant, but then why bother personalising the search in the first place if you expect users to view all 3000 anyway. You could also start with the first 500 personalized ones and then start returning all other items based on a normal open search query and filter out the 500 you already displayed.

Sorry maybe I mis-wrote but its not a 'search' functionality - yes we are using opensearch but this is actually a 'sort' for a general sale page. Think of amazon when you go on the app and select 'see more deals' and then it is all deal products. So idea being it is ranked/sorted in the sort decided by the 'AI' for that specific user. No keywords are involved only users interactions etc and the AI simply sorts the list of our 2000 products available in our weekly flash sale for that user.

So this is not a 'search result' hence why I say our customers 67% of the time scroll to the bottom of these pages as they are viewing all our flash sale items this week. The reason for personalizing is the idea that yes the first 500 are more attractive but we would like to keep it as personalised as possible throughout to 'maximise' CTA for the user even if they are down as far as the 1001st item.

"You could also start with the first 500 personalized ones and then start returning all other items based on a normal open search query and filter out the 500 you already displayed. " definitely an option but I would of assumed such limitations from the likes of Amazon would of had a solution also to go further than 500 products
